# Linking Gravitational Field Strength and Gravitational Potential confusion

Tags: gravity, potential

I want to ask a question about linking gravitational field strength **g** and gravitational potential **V**.

If I consider both quantities at a distance **r** from the centre of planet of mass **M** then I can see that they are closely related:

if $g = \frac{GM}{r^2}$ and $V = -\frac{GM}{r}$ then at a given point,

$$g = -\frac{-GM}{r}\times\frac{1}{r} = -\frac{V}{r}$$

so 
$$g = -\frac{V}{r}$$

Now, the book I am reading also states that I can link these variables through the graphs.

The rate of increase of the gravitational potential with distance **r** is known as the potential gradient, $\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta r}$ and that this value is equal to **g**, the gravitational field strength at that distance.

[image: Graph showing Gravitational Potential V against distance]

I see this is possible because using the equation we derived previously:

$$g = -\frac{V}{r}$$
$$-gr = V$$
$$-g = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta R}$$
$$g = -\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta R}$$

but my question is this:
using the graph, why can I not just take a point on the line and use the formula $g = -\frac{V}{r}$ instead of differentiation using $g = -\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta R}$ to find the value of **g** at a distance **r**?

Comment: The derivative of $-gr$ wrt $r$ is not $-g$, it is $-g - r\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}$

Comment: @Samarth I don't believe so, are you sure?

Comment: Yes, apply the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule)

Comment: @Samarth so how is the equation $g = -\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta R}$ then achieved? Is it as $\Delta R$ approaches 0, the expression is reduced to $-g$?

Comment: I just noticed, your equation $g = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$ is wrong too. Posting an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case of gravitation force, you can indeed use $g=-\frac{V}{r}$ as well as differentiate V(r):
$$
\frac{dV(r)}{dr}=-GM\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{1}{r})=GM(\frac{1}{r^2})=g
$$
I guess the book is trying to establish the more general relationship between Force (F) and Energy (E). Broadly stating: 
$$
E=\int{}{}{F}dr ==> F=\frac{dE}{dr}
$$

Comment: so both methods are valid?

Comment: Yes, for the gravitation case.

Answer (score 1):

Post the discussion in comments, here is my answer:

It is not correct to say that $g = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$, where $g$ is the magnitude of the gravitational field. The full statement for a field derived from a potential is

$$
\boldsymbol g = -\nabla V
$$

The gravitational field of a point mass is
$$
\boldsymbol g = -\frac{GM}{r^2}\hat r
$$
for which
$$
\begin{gather}
V = -\frac{GM}{r} \\
-\nabla V = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}\hat r = \frac{V}{r}\hat r
\end{gather}
$$

Taking magnitudes, we see that 
$$
\begin{gather}
g = \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} = -\frac{V}{r} \\
V = -gr \\
\end{gather}
$$

Differentiating,

$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} = -\frac{\partial (gr)}{\partial r} = -g - r\frac{\partial g}{\partial r} = -g + 2g = g
$$

which is consistent.

It is important to note that 
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} = -\frac{V}{r}
$$
is true only if
$$
V = \frac{k}{r}
$$
for some constant $k$.

Comment: Agree with the corrections but the problem is stated in scalars and I guess should be answered accordingly.

Comment: If the problem stated in scalars you're talking about is whether it is okay to use either differentiating or dividing by $r$ (with the correct signs) to find $g$, then yes, both give you the same answer.
If the problem stated in scalars is your "derivation" of $g = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$ from $-gr = V$, I have already talked about how it is wrong in the comments below your question and in my answer.